# Multiple power law plots with package poweRlaw

Tags: r, plot, power-law

I tried using the package [poweRlaw](https://github.com/csgillespie/poweRlaw) to plot a few powerlaw fits. It seems working for a single curve. But I could not plot multiple plots on the same graph.
[Ref:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14476426/how-to-plot-degree-distribution-in-r) Is there a way within this package?
[P.S. I am a novice]

```
set.seed(1)
x1 <- ceiling(rlnorm(1000, 4))

x2 <- ceiling(rlnorm(1000, 2))

library(poweRlaw)

pl_d = pl_data$new(x1)
plot(pl_d)

#Now fit the powerlaw
m = displ$new(pl_d)
#Estimate the cut-off
#estimate_xmin(m)
aaa <- estimate_xmin(m)
aaa <- as.data.frame(aaa)
aaa <- aaa[2,1]
x_min <- min(table(x))
m$setXmin(aaa); m$mle()
#Plot the data and the PL line
#plot(m)
lines(m, col=2)

# next POWER LAW graph

#Plot the data
pl_d = pl_data$new(x2)
points(pl_d)

#Now fit the powerlaw
m = displ$new(pl_d)
#Estimate the cut-off
#estimate_xmin(m)
aaa <- estimate_xmin(m)
aaa <- as.data.frame(aaa)
aaa <- aaa[2,1]
x_min <- min(table(x))
m$setXmin(aaa); m$mle()
#Plot the data and the PL line
#points(m)
lines(m, col=3)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `lines` commands to add multiple best fitting power-laws. So, using your data:

```
set.seed(1)
x1 = ceiling(rlnorm(1000, 4))
```

we load the package and create a discrete power-law object:

```
m = displ$new(x1)
```

Then plot the data

```
plot(m)
```

Next, we set `xmin` and `alpha` for each power-law and add it to the graph using `lines`:

```
m$setXmin(100)
p_100 = estimate_pars(m)
m$setPars(p_100)
lines(m, col=2, lwd=2)

##Line 2    
m$setXmin(202)
p_200 = estimate_pars(m)
m$setPars(p_200)
lines(m, col=3, lwd=2)
```

[image]

---

If you want to have multiple data sets on the same plot, the easiest way is to plot one data set, but save the data as a data frame. For example, generate some data sets:

```
set.seed(1)
x1 = ceiling(rlnorm(1000, 4))
x2 = ceiling(rlnorm(1000, 5))
```

Fit the power-laws

```
m1 = displ$new(x1)
m1$setXmin(estimate_xmin(m1))

m2 = displ$new(x2)
m2$setXmin(estimate_xmin(m2))
```

Plot data set 2, but save the data as `pts2`

```
pts2 = plot(m2)
```

Plot and add lines as normal:

```
plot(m1)
points(pts2$x, pts2$y, col=3)
lines(m1, col=2)
lines(m2, col=4)
```

to get:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Will wait for the varying "xmins" version.

Comment: Well, what I actually wanted to plot is something like the following:

![FIGURE]<img src="http://i50.tinypic.com/33x8tg7.png" width="100" height="100">

Comment: @AttuD See the updated answer. In future versions, I'll probably add an argument to the plot function to make this easier.

Comment: Thanks, I got it. And I did almost the same way you did.